# name 'get_object_or_404' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am following this tutorial: https://tutorial-extensions.djangogirls.org/en/homework_create_more_models/

Which i am adding onto a simple blog I made so i can add comments

Me error:

`name 'get_object_or_404' is not defined`

From this method in `views.py`

```
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    # post = Post
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

As you see the #hashed out line.  This allows me to get to the comment view but then then I get the error that `Cannot assign "<class 'blog.models.Post'>": "Comment.post" must be a "Post" instance.`

That makes sense but wanted to point that out.

I assume this is a database issue?

my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']
```

Everything in the tutorial has been followed to a T.  I even went through it 3 times, and re copy and pasted everything in, re migrated, etc.

Is there something I am missing the point of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the error

```
name 'get_object_or_404' is not defined
```

I looked around the blog, and they don't seem to import `get_object_or_404`. Add to the top of your code:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) is documentation on it.

Comment: Yup, glad it helped. For your second question, I'm unsure what you are asking.